# C# How to stop a Timer after 10 min

Tags: c#, timer

I tried to write some values after every 10 seconds for 10 minutes in a Text file.
My code looks like this.

```
    private void button12_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer tPOI = new DispatcherTimer();
        tPOI.Tick += new System.EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_TickPOI);
        tPOI.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        tPOI.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("recording POI");
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_TickPOI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@textBox36.Text, true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("pos POI");
            file.WriteLine(textBox40.Text);
            file.WriteLine(textBox41.Text);
            file.WriteLine(textBox42.Text);
            file.WriteLine(textBox46.Text);
        }
    }
```

But now i don't know how to stop my Timer after 10 minutes. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Call the stop method?

Comment: Use [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: either you count the amount of `dispatcherTimer_TickPOI` calls: 6 per minute for 10 minutes = 60 times. Or you have a second timer which fires after 10 Minutes and stops the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Track the `StartTime` and check if it crossed 10 mins.

```
private DateTime _startTime; //track the start time
private DispatcherTimer tPOI;

private void button12_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    tPOI = new DispatcherTimer();
    tPOI.Tick += new System.EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_TickPOI);
    tPOI.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

    _startTime = DateTime.Now; //assign start time when it actually starts

    tPOI.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("recording POI");
}

private void dispatcherTimer_TickPOI(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if (_startTime.AddMinutes(10) < DateTime.Now) //check if it has crossed 10 mins
     { 
        tPOI.Stop();
     } 
     else 
     {
         using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@textBox36.Text, true)) 
         {
             file.WriteLine("pos POI");
             file.WriteLine(textBox40.Text);
             file.WriteLine(textBox41.Text);
             file.WriteLine(textBox42.Text);
             file.WriteLine(textBox46.Text);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_startTime.AddMinutes(10) <= DateTime.Now` ?

Comment: Ahh! Yes, it should be `<` as it should also write on 10th minute.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter much in this case due to the small number of invocations (60), but using the pattern above, storing a "stop time" equal to Now+10 minutes in the "Click" method prevents having to add 10 minutes each time you check.
Also, in general I would use a count to 60 instead, if it's important that the timer fires exactly "10*60 seconds/10 seconds" times, as suggested above.